# Why doesn't a blunt-tip nail crack the wood?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, pressure, everyday-life

I came across [this video](https://youtu.be/33IDFPknShw?t=29), which shows you how to prevent the wood from cracking up at the ends while hammering a nail into it. The proposed solution is to make the nail tip blunt using a plier. This might be very obvious for many DIYers among you, but I really find it intriguing.

[image: Hammering]

It feels strange that the sharp tip cracks open the wood, whereas the blunt tip pierced through it smoothly.

So, why doesn't a blunt-tip nail crack the wood when a sharp-tip one does so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cracks form due to pressure from the nails and propagate through the weak parts of the wood. Wood is a bundle of fibers. These fibers are robust by themselves, but the bonding between individual fibers is weak. This creates weakness planes in wood (Its easy to axe wood along these planes). So if you could pull the fibers in the right direction they tear apart easily,  exactly like when you try to tear a plain fabric.

Now lets take a look at the tip of the two nails as they are hammered into the wood. The sharp tip shoves any wood particles away from its path;

[image]

While the blunt tip carries them away with it.

[image]

Normally, wooden planks used for construction has a weakness plane along its length. So when you hammer sharp tip nail into it, force exerted on the wood is in the correct direction so as to pull the fibers apart. But for the blunt tip nail, no such force is exerted. Hence, you have no splitting.

Comment: The "inefficient" blunt nail, indeed, compresses the fibers around it and strengthens the wood all around, including along the block's grain, the plane most vulnerable to splitting. But you ask and answer your own questions at the same time?

Comment: The video does not illustrate this case.  For the nail he drills a hole before hammering the nail in.  The blunt tip is for the screws.

Comment: @CosmasZachos You are always welcome to add another answer! I have been using this site for a while but haven't used the "Answer your own question" option they put below the question asking page. Thought I would give it a try :)

Comment: No, I don't have deep insights, beyond [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7rwcGXIORro) which explains the point.